# query never returning with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

There is no result and no error when I try the following locally:

```
 select
  a,
  bunch,
  of,
  fields
    from import where id in (
        SELECT distinct t1.id
        FROM import t1 inner join import t2 
        on t1.programid = t2.programid and t1.sku = t2.sku 
        where t1.lastupdated < t2.lastupdated   
    )
```

This query is part of a query to copy old records to archive this is the part fetchng the data that needs to be moved.

When I run the whole thing in cpanel's phpmydmin nothing happens, no error and no records are copied, when I run the statament that only gets the data nothing is returned, the page just sticks in loading and that's it.

There are over a million records and 2/3 needs to be archived, I have to use cpanel that has phpmyadmin but think it's unfit to run queries like that. When combined with "insert into" the above statement locks up the phpmyadmin session for 2 hours but no records are copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have have phpmyadmin do this on queries wit subselects on some versions of it.

However try this SQL, which should do the same but might be more efficient.

```
SELECT a, bunch, of, fields
    FROM import 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT distinct t1.id
        FROM import t1 inner join import t2 
        on t1.programid = t2.programid and t1.sku = t2.sku 
        where t1.lastupdated < t2.lastupdated ) Sub1
    ON import.id = Sub1.id
```

Edited to add the below code to retrieve records which do not have the latest lastupdated for each programid / sku

```
SELECT a, bunch, of, fields
FROM import 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT programid, sku, MAX(lastupdated) AS lastupdated FROM import GROUP BY programid, sku) Sub1
ON import.programid = Sub1.programid AND import.sku = Sub1.sku AND import.lastupdated = Sub1.lastupdated
WHERE Sub1.programid IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try the inner join in a couple of hours when the current query finishes. Put the statement in a stored procedure and executed it through phpmyadmin, can't get the home screen now so I guess the server is too busy executing the query. The tables are all myisam and as far as I know it doesn't support transaction so if something times out it should at leas have copied some records unless the part getting the id's takes too long and times out before it gets any id's to insert.

Comment: No, sorry. Just ran the query for 2 hours but nothing is copied and I can't see any errors.

Comment: Just ran the query: show processlist and see that there are 3 processes with the same "copy to archive" sql statements. Killed them all and ran the query from a php page I made. The process will probably take a long time (over 10 hours?) that's why I didn't see any records added to archive. Will check show processes tomorrow again. It's likely nothing will happen because mysql might kill the process after several hours.

Comment: Is this script to archive everything except the import that was updated last for a particular programid / sku?

Comment: Any programid/sku that is older, only records with the newest lastupdated will stay and be processed. I don't know if there are multiple program/sku recordsor how many but some of them have "historical" information so only need to keep the most recent one.

Comment: Just added some more code. This might be a more efficient way to get the records that are not the latest ones for a programid / sku

Comment: Thank you, current query is still running (11 hours) and is still copying records to temp table, nothing is inserted in archive yet.